# Scheduling NiFi Processor to run upon receiving the first flow file of the day

Tags: apache-nifi, scheduling

How can I schedule a NiFi processor to run only when it receives the first flow file of the day.

The processor can ignore all subsequent flowfiles.

Comment: What triggers the flow? What is the first processor?

Answer (score 0):

you need any kind of storage to remember the previous date.

as variant use DistributedMapCache to store previous date

flow:

```
----------------------> FetchDistributedMapCache - get prev date
-(success, not found)-> RouteOnAttribute  - compare previous date with current date
-(not matched)--------> PutDistributedMapCache - store new date
----------------------> next processor that triggered on date change
```